# Ctrl-D in Excel deletes contents instead of filling down

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros

Title says it all. When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, it clears the contents in the cell instead of filling down the columns.

Any idea why this could be happening and how to fix it? I reset all of my customizations but that didn't fix it.

I also tried recording a new macro for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> by clicking and dragging down the rows, but then when I use the macro it just fills those specific cells instead of any cells in the sheet.

Answer (score 0):

similar to:  https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/136584/how-to-get-google-sheets-ctrl-d-fill-down-to-behave-like-excel-when-single-cel

crtl-d works by copying the cell above to the active cell, so if the cell above is empty it copies the blank cell to the active cell (it just looks like it is clearing the content of the active cell).

Note if selecting a range of cells, the cell(s) to be copied should be the top cell(s) in the range.

Comment: The above cells are not empty. Here is an example of what I mean: https://i.imgur.com/ESeqWiS.png The cells outlined in green are selected. When I click ctrl-d, either nothing happens or the cells get cleared.

Comment: Your screenshot is showing what I would expect, you selected x08 cells and ctrl-d, which would copy what is in x07 and paste it to x08. Since x07 and x08 are the same it looks like nothing is happening. Or are you saying if you clear x08 and do the ctrl-d nothing happens?

Comment: @digitalwaterfall As gns100 explained, if you want to "fill down" cell x09 with the content of cell x08, please select x09, then press Ctrl +D. Here is an [gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/As9Vv.gif). But if you could not get such result, I suggest you check whether  the hot key of Crtl+D is occupied by other softwares.